# Are these correct steps when mergin multiple branches into Master?

Tags: git, merge

Since I am pretty new to Git (many years used SVN), I kind of messed up the git repository. I first started with one user who created 1 branch, then I switched to another user to finish the process and adding a few more branches. Since the logic of branching was totally new to me, I ended up with my 4 tasks spread in 4 branches.

After all day of research, I found a way how to put all together and merge with the master. These were my steps:

```
git branch #to see what branches I have and where I am currently in. it showed * master

git checkout master
git pull origin master
git merge task1
```

got error: Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.

```
git add *
git commit -m "merging task1"
git merge task1
```

got information: Already up-to-date.

```
git merge task2
```

got error: Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.

```
git add *
git commit -m "merging task2"
git merge task3
```

got error: Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.

And the same steps until merging all 4 tasks. In the end I pushed the code via

```
git push origin master
```

got message:

```
Counting objects: 156, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (96/96), done.
Writing objects: 100% (109/109), 259.73 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 109 (delta 56), reused 0 (delta 0)
To git@git.assembla.com:xxxxxxx.git
226887d..4bfad08  master -> master
```

I visited commits log on the Assembla git repository and saw all my branches committed and the last one as well.

Can someone tell me if my steps were OK?

I made like 100 changes to multiple files and it's impossible that I manually check if each line of the code was where it should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you resolved all the merge commits, and then pushed the changes upstream, all your code is in tact, checked into the repository.

The same is evident from the `Already up-to-date.` message you received on re-merging of branch `task1` in your second step - all the commits of `task1` are already there on `master` branch.

---

`git add conflict_file` is *the* thing to do after resolving the merge commit.

Ideally, you should add individual files in which you have resolved commits, after resolving commits, so that you don't commit an unresolved conflict file by mistake.

So, resolve merge conflict in file_1, git add file_1, resolve merge conflict in file_2, git add file_2, and so on, and finally make the commit.

This way you can keep track of all added files.

However, since there are a 100 files in your case, I think you can cut out the redundant step of adding files individually - `git add *` will add them all in a single go.

Comment: Actually the `git add *` mostly confused me. Is this a regular thing when merging? Cause some of those files existed in the master and were later changed in the branch.